# How I can assign radio button value in a particular entity

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application and using JSP.
In my application, I want to assign the value of radio button in the variable called **availability** of my entity class. I did not find any proper solution on the internet. 
Can any one tell me how I can get the value using `${product.availability}` in my jsp file?

This is my entity:

```
private boolean availability; 

public boolean isAvailability() {
    return availability;
}

public void setAvailability(boolean availability) {
    this.availability = availability;
}
```

This is my radio button code:

```
<input type="radio" name="available" value="true" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="available" value="false" /> No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. 
In the line

```
<input type="radio" class="col-sm-1" name="available" value="true"/>
```

just changed the `name= "availability"` which matches my variable name `private boolean availability;`